# Submit button does not appear in Firefox but on Chrome and Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, php, html, firefox

Like the title says, this does not appear on Firefox:

```
<form class = "form-buy" action="buy-form.php" method="post">
    <input name="lp_current" type="hidden" id="lp-current2">
    <input name="server_current" type="hidden" id="server-current2">
    <input name="amount" type="hidden" value="" id="divisions-cost">
    <input name="discount_amount" type="hidden" value="" id="divisions-cost-discount">
    <input name="discount_rate" type="hidden" value="" id="divisions-discount-rate">
    <input name="item_name" type="hidden" id="divisions-item-name" value="">
    <input name="submit" type="submit"  value="Buy Boost" id="divisions-buy-button">
</form>
```

My other submit button for my other form works on Firefox, however:

```
form id="contactform" name="contactform" class="contactform" action="contact.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validate('contactform');">
    <label class = "col1 first" for="sender"><font color=red>*</font>E-mail:</label>
    <input class = "col4" type="text" name="sender" id="sender"  />
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <label class = "col1 first" for="IGN">IGN:</label>
    <input class = "col4" type="text" name="IGN" id="IGN" />
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <label class="col1 first" for="message"><font color=red>*</font>Message:</label>
    <textarea class="col5" rows="5" name="message" id="message"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value = "submit" />
</form>
```

Okay, so I tried the closing tags, and turns out that the submit button is hiding under some text and an image.

Solution:
Turns out that I had "overflow: hidden;" in my css file, and that was what made it hidden. Thanks for the responses.

Comment: Do you have anything different in your CSS between these two forms? In the form that doesn't work you have an id assigned to the submit button. Have you tried just putting a <input type="submit" value="Buy Boost" /> to see if it shows? Also, you can try to use <button type="submit">Buy Boost"</button>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gareth could be correct, but I would also check your CSS, jQuery, or something else you have upstream that may be hiding the button. The fact that your button isn't visible would tell me that it isn't necessarily a syntax problem. However, you should do as Gareth suggested and use a self closing tag.

In your form that works you don't have an id associated with your submit button, but you do in your form that doesn't work. This leads me to believe you probably have something controlling this button either in your CSS, jQuery, AngularJS, etc... If you change your submit button on your form that doesn't work to something like this:

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Buy Boost" />
```

or

```
<button type="submit">Buy Boost</button>
```

Do either of these work or at least show the button?

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, I would have commented but I don't have 50 reputation yet..

Not sure it's causing the problem but recommended to change for valid HTML.. be sure to close your input tags, they're self closing tags so it should be as follows (as in your second form).

```
<input type="x" name="y" />
```

*note the forward slash before the last angle bracket*

JSFiddle with valid code - http://jsfiddle.net/62bfj1f0/

Hope this helps,
Gareth

Comment: Might not have been the answer but a down vote is a little harsh, don't you think? :)